# Merging multiple text files into one dataframe

Tags: r, merge

I have this reproducible set up.

```
temp <- tempfile()
download.file("https://d396qusza40orc.cloudfront.net/getdata%2Fprojectfiles%2FUCI%20HAR%20Dataset.zip",temp)
datafiles <- unzip(temp)
unlink(temp)
```

Printing `datafiles` gives a range of txt files.
I can manually merge them by...

```
mdataset = merge(mydata1.txt, mydata2.txt)
mdataset = merge(mydataset, mydata3.txt)
.
.
.
mytempdata = merge(mytempdata, mydata20.txt)
```

But this would take a while, and I would rather do it more efficiently.

How would I do this (elegantly)?

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm wondering instead of renaming my files, would it be possible to get it to read by the .txt pattern within ```datafiles``` ?

Comment: The zip file is the [Public Domain Data Set for Human Activity Recognition Using Smartphones](http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Human+Activity+Recognition+Using+Smartphones) data, used for the final project in Johns Hopkins Getting & Cleaning Data course on Coursera. The files include test data, training data, and data dictionaries. You can't just merge them into a single data frame via Reduce. One needs to understand how each file is used to create the test and training data sets and code accordingly.

Comment: @LenGreski. Thanks for replying. Thanks for pointing out about reduce. 
I'm having trouble where R is sending me the message " Error: cannot allocate vector of size 15.6 Mb ".  How can I resolve this? Because using memory.limit() tells me that I still have 16Gb memory.

Comment: How much RAM do you have on your machine, and what R function were you using when the memory allocation failed?